# open office (from krusader) can't open remote files

Tags: ubuntu, openoffice

I use ubuntu and have an samba share. From file browser I can open files from samba with open office but from krusader it makes a local copy in /tmp and open that temp file instead of original file. Same issue with gnome commander.

How can I open files with open office from samba share using krusader?

Comment: Do you have kdebase-kio-plugins installed? You can check by typing:

aptitude show kdebase-kio-plugins

into a terminal. You need this to be able to use SMB in Krusader.

Comment: Is it possible that the file is opened in tmp on your local machine, but that changes are written back to the original samba share version when you close the file?

Comment: ~# aptitude show kdebase-kio-plugins
No current or candidate version found for kdebase-kio-plugins
Package: kdebase-kio-plugins
State: not a real package

The file is open in tmp and when I save it save in tmp not on samba server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the permissions set correctly on your SMB share?  Specifically that you have write permissions.  Krusader may be recognizing that you cannot write to the share and thus caching the file in the /tmp directory.

Comment: yes I have write permission, I can modify other files, but if I open them with open office I can't modify.

Answer (score 0):

Different applications interact with samba shares differently, depending on how the share is mounted. I don't really understand why, but I have noticed that they do.

For example, when I use **Places -> Connect to Server** to connect to a file share, i.e., Gnome's Nautilus, I can save to that location with Open Office. Specifically, the share shows up "Places" column in the "Save" dialog box. On the other hand, if I try to save a file downloaded through Firefox, I don't see the share listed in Firefox's "Save" dialog box.

Knowing that Gnome Nautilus on Ubuntu uses Fuse and GVFS to mount the samba share, I experimented and found that, like if I was trying to access the share from a shell, I need to navigate into `~/.gvfs/` directory. Try as I might, I could not create a shortcut in the Nautilus Bookmarks directly to the `~/.gvfs/` directory - Nautilus always converted the bookmark into a form that Firefox ignored.

What I finally did was mount the desired share from the commandline with the `mount.cifs` command. This created an entry in the "Places" column of Firefox's "Save" dialog box.

I wonder if, like Firefox, krusader is not interoperating with GVFS. If that is the case, one possible solution is to mount the samba share from the /etc/fstab or with the `mount.cifs` command.